# Any Javascript and PHP AJAX Interface generation suggestions, like thrift?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, rpc, thrift

I am basically looking for Apache Thrift, but to talk between JavaScript over Ajax and PHP.
I know Thirft generates both, but to my knowledge the JavaScript code must talk over JSONProtocol, of which the protocol isn't yet wrote in PHP.

Are there any other alternatives that can suggested?

If you are unfamiliar with Thrift, this is a simple(ish) definition of what i need:

Consider this as the generic interface definition language (IDL), where I setup a User object, an AuthenticationResult result object, and method named UserCommands.Authenticate();

```
struct User {
    1:  number          id,
    2:  string          firstName,
    3:  string          lastName
}

struct AuthenticationResult {
    1:  number              currentTime,
    2:  User            user
}

service UserCommands {
    AuthenticationResult        Authenticate(1:string username, 2:string password)
}
```

I run a program or something, it creates JS and PHP libraries based on the above.

Then, in JS, I could call (with helpful typehinting).

```
var myAuthResult = UserCommands.Authenticate('myUser', 'myPass');
alert ("My first name is : " + myAuthResult.user.firstName);
```

And in PHP, I would setup a method in a UserCommands class like this:

```
function Authenticate($username, $password) {
   $myUser = new User();
   $myUser->firstName = "Fred";
   $myUser->lastName = "Thompson";
   $myAuthResult = new AuthenticationResult ();
   $myAuthResult->currentTime = date("U");
   $myAuthResult->user = $myUser;
   return $myAuthResult;
}
```

The benefits are that PHP can return native objects and JS can expect to receive its own native objects.
Type hinting for available methods are provided through out, with expected params and return results.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there're `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions in php.
Secondly, there's a serialize/unserialize for native php types
I don't understand, though, which you mean under *"... of which the protocol isn't yet wrote in PHP."*

Also, there's a [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) langauge, which can be "compiled" into both PHP and JavaScript (and some other languages)

Comment: Im aware of the encode/decode and serialize/unserialize methods, but its the format of the JSON message that the Thrift doesn't currently 'decode'. 

There is generally a file named TJSONProtocol in Thrift which handles the messages and converts the JSON into Thrift objects.

Its a bit of a biggie to write the TJSONProtocol from scratch, as you need to know the format/schema of the messages that Thrift uses.

Comment: That said, Haxe is possibly what i'm after. I actually forgot about it (I used to use it for flash). I'll take a quick look.